# How to push data from a nested array, inside an array of objects, to a new array? while maintaining its nested structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains multiple objects. These objects also contain arrays of objects like this:

```
const data =
    [
        {
            id: 1, name: "Jack", interests: 
            [
                {id: 9, name: "basketball"},
                {id: 8, name: "art"}
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2, name: "Jenny", interests: 
            [
                {id: 7, name: "reading"},
                {id: 6, name: "running"}
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I would like to push both interests arrays into a new array like so:

```
newArray = 
    [
        [{id: 9, name: "basketball"}, {id: 8, name: "art"}],
        [{id: 7, name: "reading"},{id: 6, name: "running"}]
    ];
```

This pushes the data to the new array, but the data isn't nested anymore this way:

```
data.map(v => { v.interests.map(x => { newArray.push({name: x.name, id:x.id}) }) })
```

How can I push the interests data to new array while keeping its nested structure?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just `.map` the `interests` of each item:

```js
const data=[{id:1,name:"Jack",interests:[{id:9,name:"basketball"},{id:8,name:"art"}]},{id:2,name:"Jenny",interests:[{id:7,name:"reading"},{id:6,name:"running"}]}]
const mapped = data.map(({ interests }) => interests);
console.log(mapped);
```

When mapping, you don't want to use `push` to a new array you've created beforehand; instead you want to use `return` (or use an arrow function's implicit return) for each new array item. (You're currently using the `.map` as a `forEach`)

If you don't want to *just* map the `interests` array and need to transform the objects as well, then it's a bit more complicated; you'll have to use a nested `map` as well:

```js
const data=[{id:1,name:"Jack",interests:[{id:9,name:"basketball",foo:'bar'},{id:8,name:"art",foo:'bar'}]},{id:2,name:"Jenny",interests:[{id:7,name:"reading",foo:'bar'},{id:6,name:"running",foo:'bar'}]}]
const mapped = data.map(({ interests }) =>
  // Use only `id` and `foo` properties, discard the `name`s:
  interests.map(({ id, foo }) => ({ id, foo }))
);
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: thanks I got it, how about if you want to choose which properties return in the new array? Right now there are only two properties, name and id, but there could be more. I might not want to return all of them.

Comment: MIght be clearer to do `data.map( (person) => person.interests )`, or do you gain something from the syntax you're using maybe I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Tibrogargan IMO, destructuring is often preferable. If you only need a particular property of an object, and you don't need the whole object, then often it's nicer to simply extract that property as a variable rather than declare an object and proceed to use only use one property of the object.